# Evaluating a 2part Taylor Polynomial with degree 2

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Question:
(a) Find the Taylor polynomial of degree 2 of the given function at $=0$.

This is the given function: $()=e^{-5}$

I determined and verified my answer:$1−5 + \frac{25}{2}x^2$

(b) Find an approximate value of $e^{-0.5}$ using the Taylor polynomial of degree 2 that you computed in (a).

I've tried almost everything — plugged $e^{-0.5}$ into my Taylor polynomial in (a), plugged $0.5$, $0$, and $1/e^{0.5}$. 
What is it that I'm missing here? All that I'm certain of here is that the Taylor polynomial I got in (a) is to be used.

Comment: plug $x=0.1$ in your expansion maybe...

Comment: how'd you arrive at x = 0.1? @zwim

Comment: well $-5x=-0.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial $p_2$ approximates $f$ in the near of $x_0 = 0$. If you want to approximate $\mathrm e^{-0.5}$, you have to evaluate the polynomial in the point $x^\ast$ in which $f$ attains the value $\mathrm e^{-0.5}$. But it is clear that the equation $f(x^\ast) = \mathrm e^{-5x^\ast} = \mathrm e^{-0.5}$ has the unique solution $x^\ast = 0.1$, since by taking logarithms you get $-5x^\ast = -0.5$, and then you only have to divide by $-5$. Hence,

$$\mathrm e^{-0.5} \approx p_2(x^\ast) = 1 - 5 \cdot 0.1 + \frac{25}{2} \cdot (0.1)^2 = \dots$$